# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to read serial data from a DMM and I think that the data gets corrupted sporadically.  About 95% of the time I can read the data and display it to a textBox just fine but very once in a while I get this error:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled in mscorlib.dll.

The InnerException is: Message=Input string was not in a correct format.

I'm new to Windows WPF and C# programming but I think this means that the data that is received wasn't terminated properly.

Here is my Receive() code:

```
 private delegate void UpdateUiTextDelegate(string text);
    private void Recieve(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Collecting the characters received to our 'buffer' (string).
        received_data = serial.ReadLine();
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new UpdateUiTextDelegate(WriteData), received_data);            
    }
```

What's the proper way to handle corrupted data?

UPDATE: Here's my writeData():

```
 private void WriteData(string text)
    {
        string myTextStripped;
        string avgText;
        string textChar;
        string currentFilteredText;
        double current;
        double difference;
        int range;
        textBox2.Text = myText;                 // display raw string data
        myTextStripped = text.Substring(1, 7);  // remove chars after 7th char
        myTextStrippedTextBox.Text = myTextStripped;  // display trimmed string

        if (myTextStripped[5] == '2')           // range 0 - 59.9 mV
        {
            range = 1;
            myTextStripped = myText.Remove(4);  // keep first 4 chars
            current = float.Parse(myTextStripped);
            current = current / 100;
            myTextStrippedTextBox.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
        }
        else if (myTextStripped[5] == '3')      // range is 60mV - 600mV
        {
            range = 2;
            myTextStripped = myText.Remove(4);  // keep first 4 chars
            current = float.Parse(myTextStripped);
            current = current / 10;
            myTextStrippedTextBox.Background = Brushes.YellowGreen;
        }
        else                                    // range is 600mv+
        {
            range = 3;
            myTextStripped = myText.Remove(4);  // keep first 4 chars
            current = float.Parse(myTextStripped);
            myTextStrippedTextBox.Background = Brushes.PaleVioletRed;
        }
        // Filter results because readings jump too much to visually determine a good value
        difference = (current - currentFiltered);          
        currentFiltered = currentFiltered + (filterFactor * difference);

        avgText = currentFiltered.ToString(".000");
        avgText = avgText.TrimStart('0');
        currentTextBox.Text = avgText;
    }
```

Comment: Not necessarily, it may mean that you have a something`.Parse` that has an invalid format. Can you show the code where you use the data? Or is this a data binding on some control? If so, please show the binding.

Comment: Seems like the problem is inside your WriteData method. Is it a method implemented by you? If it is, please, send that method too.

Comment: Well, nothing to do with "not terminated properly", or ReadLine() won't complete.  You need to add logging so you can record the bad strings you get, do so in a catch {}.  And you need to implement the ErrorReceived event handler so you *know* you got an error.

Comment: Before everything, I strongly suggest that you should ALWAYS use TryParse instead of Parse in all possible cases. Kinda think Microsoft should've banned the Parse API. Agree with @Hans Passant. You need to put a logger in order to tell what's wrong.  Things like myTextStripped/myText has no basic validation or logging in your code. It's kinda hard to tell what's wrong when unexpected siutation happened.